# Polygon Filling | Scan Line Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, polygon, fill, polyfills

I'm developing a Game like [paper.io](http://paper-io.com/) in C++ with Win32 API. My Game data is stored in an array like:

1 = Player's Head

2 = Player's base

3 = Player's tail

---

1. 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
2. 0, 0, **3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,** 0, 0, 0, **3, 3, 3, 3,** 0, 0, 0, 0,
3. 0, 0, **3,** 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, **3,** 0, 0, 0, **3,** 0, 0, **3,** 0, 0, 0, 0,
4. 0, 0, **3,** 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, **3, 3, 3, 3, 3,** 0, 0, **3,** 0, 0, 0, 0,
5. 0, 0, **3,** 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, **3,** 0, 0, 0, 0,
6. 0, 0, *2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,* 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, **3, 3, 3, 3,** 0,
7. 0, 0, *2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,* 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, **3,** 0,
8. 0, 0, *2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,* **1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,** 0,
9. 0, 0, *2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,* 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
10. 0, 0, *2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,* 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
11. 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,

---

Now I want to fill the polygon (Player's tail) with the Number 2 (Player's base).

[Scan Line Algorithm](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_graphics/polygon_filling_algorithm.htm):

> What works:
>
> > 1. If I scan the 5. line The first 3 trigger the algorithm and toggle the painting function. The next 3 toggles it again it stops the painting function again
>
> Problems:
>
> > 1. If I scan the 2. line After Every 3 the painting function will be toggled and after the line, it will paint further, because it's an odd amount of numbers.
>
> Solutions:
>
> > 1. Toggle on the transition from zero to non-zero (and non-zero to zero)

[Boundary Fill Algorithm](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_graphics/polygon_filling_algorithm.htm):

> Problems:
>
> > 1. I need to find the middle/spot to begin, that's in the polygon

Comment: You don't toggle for each consecutive non-zero value. You toggle on the transition from zero to non-zero (and non-zero to zero).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of special cases that make it tricky to determine which areas are inside the new base vs. outside, but this one is simple and reliable:

1. Do a flood fill starting at the outer edges to find the area that is *not* in the base.  This fill can cover any color except 1, 2, and 3
2. Fill *everything else* with color 2 to make the new base.